# Convert React Class to a Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

On my [older repository](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/jamesprentice-css-help/client/components), I have used Class Components with the following CruiseListHeader component code, as an example (used for showing Cruise Buttons).

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {getCruiseLines} from '../api/api'
    import ListofShips from './ListofShips'
    
    
    class CruiseListHeader extends React.Component {
        constructor(props)  {
            super(props)
    
            //setting intial state for Cruise Headings and initialize cruiseHeaders as an empty array
            this.state = {
                cruiseHeaders: []
            } 
            
            //binding methods for setting up Cruise Line Headings
            this.setUpCruiseLines = this.setUpCruiseLines.bind(this)
        }  
    
        componentDidMount() {
            console.log('cdm')
            this.setUpCruiseLines()
        }
    
        setUpCruiseLines()  {
            console.log('getcruiselines')
            getCruiseLines()
                .then(res   =>  {
    
                    this.setState({
                        cruiseHeaders: res
                    })
                })
        }
         
        render()    {
            return  (

            <React.Fragment>

                {/* There will be Headings for all the Cruise Lines. */}
                {/* Map the Cruiseline Headings for each Ship to display them on the page. I want to map ship, because I need each ship displayed in a List, when Cruise Line Heading is clicked. */}

            <div className = "cruiseContainer">

                {this.state.cruiseHeaders.map (ship =>  {
                
                    return (

                    <div key={ship.cruise_line}>

                        {/* ListofShips component needs cruise_line, because when user clicks on Cruise Line Heading button,
                            we need to fetch ships that belongs to that particular cruiseline. */}
                        {/* We need to render multiple ListofShips components, with one for each cruiseline */}
                        <ListofShips cruise_line={ship.cruise_line}></ListofShips>

                    </div>
                    )

                })}

            </div>      

            </React.Fragment> 
        )
    }
} 

export default CruiseListHeader
```

Please note that this is all related to a Cruise Lines Page shown below, that has a main  [CruiseLines.jsx](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/jamesprentice-css-help/client/components/CruiseLines.jsx#L3) component with the CruiselistHeader.jsx mentioned above imported into it.

[Cruise Buttons on Cruise lines Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnnN0.png)

Now I want to start the change by converting this React Class Component into a Functional one.

This is what I have for my CruiseListHeader as a Functional Component, so far.

Please note that ListofShips is now called ShipsList in this [new repository](https://github.com/JamesPrenticez/cruise-ships/tree/cruiselines/client/components).

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {getCruiseLines } from '../api/api'
import ShipsList from './ShipsList'

function CruiseListHeader() {

    // Declare cruiseHeaders State variable 
    const [cruiseHeaders] = useState({
        
    })

    useEffect (() =>    {

    // Note: This was the original ComponentDidMount that took Binding this.setUpCruiseLines()
    // Now it is coming from the CruiseListHeader.js useEffect to the DOM    
    }
    )
    

    return  (
        <>
        <div>    
            <div key={ship.cruise_line}>
                <ShipsList cruise_line={ShipsList.cruise_line}></ShipsList>            
            </div>
        </div>    
        </>
    )
}

export default CruiseListHeader
```

What I am wanting to understand, is how does the Functional Component handle the state from my api, the binding and the mapping that I was previously using in my Class Component ?

If anyone has any ideas of how I can handle this, then that would be of great valuable help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the *setter* for the state, your `useState` line should be:

```
const [cruiseHeaders, setCruiseHeaders] = useState({});
```

Then you'd use that `setCruiseHeaders` function to set the state:

```
useEffect (() => {
  getCruiseLines()
    .then(res => {
      setCruiseHeaders({
        cruiseHeaders: res
      })
    });
}, []); // Make sure to also pass an array here, or you'll be triggering this effect on every render
```

As an aside, you *probably* meant to initialize your state value to an *array* instead of an object:

```
const [cruiseHeaders, setCruiseHeaders] = useState([]);
```

Since the "cruise headers" data in your original code was an array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can see that the Functional Component, is more efficient for setting state than the Class Component.


I just wonder how does the mapping work with React Functional Components ?

Comment: @RobWilkinson: That entirely depends on whatever you mean by "the mapping"?

Comment: I am relating to this in my original class component.

render()    {
            return  (

            <React.Fragment>

            <div className = "cruiseContainer">

                {this.state.cruiseHeaders.map (ship =>  {
                
                    return (

                    <div key={ship.cruise_line}>
                        <ListofShips cruise_line={ship.cruise_line}></ListofShips>

                    </div>
                    )

                })}
            </div>      
            </React.Fragment> 
        )
    }

Comment: How that code from my original class component, I have just shown  in my last comment, gets converted for the Functional Component.

Comment: @RobWilkinson: Why would the use of `.map()` be any different?  `.map()` isn't something specific to React, it's a function on JavaScript arrays.  If what you have is an array, you can call `.map()` on it.  If you've made some attempt and something isn't working as expected, that sounds like the potential for a new Stack Overflow question.

Comment: My question mentions, What I am wanting to understand, is how does the Functional Component handle the state from my api, the binding and the mapping that I was previously using in my Class Component ? 
I can see in your answer that state from api is covered and binding does not happen with functional components.
I just would like to get an understanding on how {this.state.cruiseHeaders.map (ship => is different with React functional components.

Comment: @RobWilkinson: You'd just reference the variable directly instead of `this.state`.  So in the above code you would use `cruiseHeaders.map(/*...*/)`.  There's nothing particularly special about it just because it's React.  The component is a JavaScript function, the variable declarations are local variables in that function.  This is plain JavaScript code like anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the help David, I have put my Answer up, which I assume is correct for this CruiseListHeader above.

Comment: David, I have since put another post up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73123036/how-to-handle-a-button-with-a-list-in-a-react-functional-component , that relates to my ShipsList Component following on from this.
I just want to get an understanding on how a handleClick button uses hasFetched and isOpen along with prevstate for ShipsList as a Functional Component, as I believe mine is not quite correct yet.
I have put my ShipsList Functional Component code that I have attempted towards bottom of post and also included a screenshot of how page looks when button is open with list.

Comment: David, in case you are wondering my post that follows on from this one is called "How to handle a Button with a List in a React Functional Component".

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {getCruiseLines } from '../api/api'
import ShipsList from './ShipsList'

function CruiseListHeader() {

    // Declare cruiseHeaders variable and set it's array using useState 
    const [cruiseHeaders, setCruiseHeaders] = useState([]);    
    
    // Note: This was the original ComponentDidMount that took Binding this.setUpCruiseLines()
    // Now it is coming from CruiseListHeader.jsx useEffect to the DOM    

    useEffect (() => {
        getCruiseLines()
          .then(res => {
            setCruiseHeaders({
              cruiseHeaders: res
            })
          });
      }, []); // Make sure to also pass an array here, or you'll be triggering this effect on every render

    return  (
        <>

        {/* <div className = "cruiseContainer"> I don't think I need this because I am using Tailwind CSS*/}
        {/* When I use Sass in my next final repo I may not need a div either */}

            {cruiseHeaders.map (ship => {

                // return  ( Do not need return here, I think

                    <div key = {ship.cruise_line}>

                        {/* ListofShips component needs cruise_line, because when user clicks on 
                        Cruise Line Heading button, we need to fetch ships that belongs to that particular 
                        cruiseline. */}
                        {/* We need to render multiple ShipsList components, with one for each cruiseline */}
                        <ShipsList cruise_line={ship.cruise_line}/>

                        {/* </ShipsList>  I think I don't I need this closing tag*/}
                    </div>

                // ) I think, I do not need return closing bracket here
            })}
        {/* </div> I think, I do not need closing div from cruiseContainer here*/}

        </>
    )
}

export default CruiseListHeader
```